# Connect Excel 2013 to Oracle 11 g 64 bit

Tags: excel, oracle

My laptop is Windows 8 64 bit. I installed Oracle 11g DB 64 bit on the same laptop.
My toad is working properly.
Now i am learning Power PIVOT option in Oracle ( It is really POWER). I want to connect oracle database from my laptop.

I am unable to connect Oracle.

In control panel--created   USER DSN. -  Tested working successfully. But while  trying to connecting thru Data... unable to connect.
Can anybody provide me correct steps to connect to excel.
Thanks

Comment: I assume your Excel is 32 bit. This required also an 32 bit Oracle Client, otherwise is does not work. Here is an instruction how install both 32 and 64 bit Oracle Client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Thanks for your notification of Excell 32 bit.. Upon your comment i downloaded  32 Bit oracle client .  Now  i am able to connect from excel to Oracle.  .  Thanks --Wernfried